# Problemas al extraer varios json con consultas en un modulo de nodejs

Tags: mysql, nodejs, sql, callback

Tengo un modulo en una ruta que necesita devolver un json con el contenido de varias consultas realizadas en el mismo modulo y algunas de estas consultas se realizan con datos extraídos de las primeras consultas, mi código es similar al siguiente, pero el problema lo tengo a la hora de extraer los datos, ni con `callback` ni con `promise` he conseguido extraer de forma `sincrona` los valores de las consultas para poder devolver el json compuesto de las consultas, en algunos sitios contestan con que es imposible, yo creo que estoy verde y debe ser una chorrada, no creo que en un modulo no se pueda devolver un `array/json/string` con un compuesto de varias consultas a base de datos, por favor alguien puede ayudarme llevo ya varios días y con varios métodos y no consigo que funcione de ninguna forma.

Mi objetivo a groso modo seria el siguiente:

```
var sql_ejecutar ="select * from tabla_generica";
              var json1=  conexion.query(sql_ejecutar, function(err, results, fields)
                    {
                        //Contenido en results, devue   
                    }); 


    conexion.end();
              var json2=  conexion.query(sql_ejecutar, function(err, results, fields)
                    {
                        //Contenido en results, devue   
                    }); 


    conexion.end();
              var json3=  conexion.query(sql_ejecutar, function(err, results, fields)
                    {
                        //Contenido en results, devue   
                    }); 


conexion.end();
var json_devolver[0]['json1']=json1;
var json_devolver[0]['json2']=json2;
var json_devolver[0]['json3']=json3;
res.json(json_devolver);
```

¿como hacerlo de forma correcta dentro del mismo modulo de NodeJS?

Answer (score 0):

Es una función asincrónica, para devolver los datos tenés que recibirlos en otra función asincrónica (callbacks). Algo así como

```
function procesar3sql(){
    var sql_ejecutar ="select * from tabla_generica";
    conexion.query(sql_ejecutar, function(err, result1, field1){
        conexion.query(sql_ejecutar, function(err, result2, field2){
            conexion.query(sql_ejecutar, function(err, result3, fields){
                res.json({json1: result1, json2: result2, json3: result3});
                conexion.end();
            });
        });
    }); 
}
procesar3sql();
```

Comment: En la consulta intermedia me dara varias lineas con unos id que tendria que pasar en vairas consultas a la ultima funcion, por lo que no podria encadenarlos asi ya que la ultima llamada iria en un bucle segun el resultado de la consulta intermedia, la respuesta en el json tendria que ser algo tal que asi,, un json encadenado, no uno detras de otro, es una escuela donde en el json rincipal solo muestra datos de escuela, en el campo clases aparece json con las clases y dentro del json con clases hay un campo con un json de los alumnos por cada clase encadenados de esa manera como podria hacerlo.

Comment: Entiendo. Mi respuesta contesta (lo mejor que pude) tu pregunta (que no tenía un bucle). Si te sirve la respuesta (porque te acerca, porque te enseñó algo, por lo que sea) podés indicarlo con la flecha hacia arriba. Si tienes otra pregunta lo ideal es que abras otra pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Ya que es asincrónica, debes devolver el resultado en el callback. ¿Qué significa esto?

Si tienes una función que hace una operación asincrónica, en este caso una consulta mysql, debe ser como el siguiente ejemplo:

```
function consultar (params = {}, callback) {
  conexion.query(sql, function (err, res, fields) {
    if (err) return callback(err)
    callback(null, res, fields)
  })
}
```

Donde *callback* es una función, es decir, pasas por parámetro una función que será el callback a la hora que la invoques así:

```
consultar({id: 1}, function(err, res, fields) {
  if (err) throw err
  console.log(res)
  console.log(fields)
})
```

¿Ves el callback? la variable callback que pasas como segundo parámetro en la función consultar es la función que estás usando para obtener el resultado. Otra observación es que si la consulta genera error, el callback sólo recibirá el error y no res ni fields, pero si no hay error, entonces se le pasa null, res y fields, es decir, si no existe error le pasas un null.

Una vez explicado esto, una manera de solucionar tu problema es algo como lo que sigue:

```
function consultar3Querys (params = {}, callback) {
  conexion.query(sql, function (err, res, fields) {
    if (err) return callback(err)
    conexion.query(sql, function (err, res, fields) {
      if (err) return callback(err)
      conexion.query(sql, function (err, res, fields) {
        if (err) return callback(err)
        callback(res, fields)
      })
    })
  })
}


consultar({id: 1}, function(err, res, fields) {
  if (err) throw err
  var datos = { dato1: res.dato1, dato2: res.dato2, datoN: res.datoN}
})
```

Esto funciona, pero es una mala práctica y se le conoce como **callback hell** por lo que es recomendable usar promesas.

Comment: Como bien dices desencadena un calback hell, las consultas que quiero hacer requieren un poco de programacion intermedia para interpretar los datos, por lo que entre la concatenacion de las consultas, los controles y la gestion de los callbacks el codigo se vuelve algo ilegible, lo de las promesas lo intente pero se ve que mi conocimiento no es lo suficientemente profundo, podrías indicarme el ejemplo con promesas por favor. También puede ser un fallo de lógica por mi parte, hay alguna forma de hacer estas consultas de una forma más simple o sincrona en node o estoy encabezonado en esto...?

Comment: @RafaelLozanoRuiz revisa este link: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise porque si hay lógica de por medio va a ser casi imposible para mí colocar el código que realmente te sirva

Comment: Quizá quieras editar tu pregunta porque te refieres a cómo extraer varios json (json? uno pensaría que te refieres a archivos .json y no objetos). En este momento veo dos respuestas, la mía y la de Emilio y respondemos maso menos lo mismo (aunque yo doy un ejemplo más extendido) y eso resuelve *Cómo extraer información de varias consultas*